# Cómo subir un .aab a play console que sea mayor a 150mb

Tags: servidor, unity3d, google-play, google-play-console, bundler

Buenas compañeros tengo una duda con un proyecto indie que estoy llevando, es un juego android y tengo un problema al subirlo a play console ya que me exige que el archivo .aab sea menos a 150mb pero he visto muchas aplicaciones que pesan mucho más, también tengo entendido que hay aplicaciones que suben el instalador en formato .aab y luego el resto de la aplicación se descarga desde el instalador, que maneras hay para poder almacenar esos archivos en algún servidor o algúna nube gratuita ya que mi juego pesa 350mb y deseo actualizar para que pese un poco más

Comment: https://youtu.be/lDNQVlAt7kQ

Comment: Hola. En tu caso lo primero que haría sería reducir, optimizar y ofuscar el código, aplicando las [reglas recomendadas por Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?hl=es-419). Al hacer esto el tamaño de la aplicación se reducirá de una forma considerable. Si aún así sigue excediendo el máximo permitido entonces sí podrías pensar en subir la aplicación por partes, o crear una base de datos que se sincronice posteriormente desde una fuente de datos remota (un servidor propio, Firebase, etc).

Comment: Un consejo, si te decides por aplicar lo que Android recomienda (enlace de mi anterior comentario). Antes de publicar tu aplicación, genera un APK firmado y pruébalo en un dispositivo real instalando ese APK. Lo digo porque cuando aplicas reglas de Proguard, puede que algunas clases básicas para el funcionamiento de la App no se incluyan y eso hará que la App no funcione cuando la descarguen desde Play Store. Esos errores no se ven en fase de depuración, debes probarlo instalando como APK para asegurarte de que todo funciona bien.

Comment: Ya la aplicación está en playstore, ya está funcionando, hay más de 11k de descargas pero deseo actualizar la aplicación para añadir más cosas y eso aumentará el peso, ya la aplicación está optimizada y le reduje todo lo que era capaz de reducirse