# ¿Como puedo subir un .aab a play store si pesa mas de 200 mb?

Tags: servidor, unity, unity3d, google-play, vuforia

Buen dia. 
Realice un aplicacion en Unity y Vuforia, el apk quedo bien ahora que quiero subirlo a Google no me deja porque el .aab pesa mas de 200mb, ya baje los recursos de todo los modelos, texturas y asi solo hay uno que es el mas pesado que simplemente no baja el peso del archivo.
Segun vi que debo subirlo como aparte pero no se como hacerlo, la verdad soy nuevo en todo esto.
Como lo puedo hacer para que ya esta la app.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/play-asset-delivery.html

Comment: Ya hicieron esa pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/611113/169744

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.